# Exe4J all library?

Tags: java, exe4j

I managed to solve my problem with Exe4J with "Jar in Exe" mode, after add all my library is working....Now I am looking for any way to add all library at once.
Using Exe4J GUI, I did add one by one, but I have much more that 100 library and add one by one is very hard.

here how I did make: 
[image]

There a way to add all library at once ? How to ?

thanks.

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368304/exe4j-work-but

Comment: but I don't understand why closed the topic...Affsss tense !!!

Comment: It was closed because it was unclear. Then it is better to edit the question to get it unclosed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. The .exe4j file (the saved configuration) is just a xml file. It contains a node called `<classPath>` in which the jar entries are written like so:

```
<classPath>
     <archive location="./xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar" failOnError="true" />
</classPath>
```

You can write a simple java app that iterates over your libraries' location, prints them out in the xml file (the .exe4j file) and saves it. Then, when you open the file with the exe4j programme, the libraries will be loaded.
Cheers! :)